# How to disable ListTile?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to disable the ListTile when at least one character is entered into the text field. I wrote the code, but I don’t understand how to write a function for `onChanged`. How can I do this?

```dart
    bool _isEnableTile = true;

    ListTile(
     ...
      onTap: _isEnableTile
          ? () => _selectPosition(_positionsList![index].id)
          : null,
    );

    TextField(
      onChanged: _onChangedPosition,
    ),

    void _onChangedPosition(text) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This if you got any error let me know.

```
bool isAble=true;
ListTile(
            title: const Text("Lable"),
            enabled: isAble,
          ),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              if (value.length > 0) {
                setState(() {
                  isaAble = false;
                });
              }
            },
          )
```